# How to install different versions of modules for python

Tags: python, pip, python-module

I'm wondering how to install two different versions of a module for python. I host some scripts on a server and some particular ones require older version of the module because some things just doesn't work in the newer version and vice versa, some things doesn't work on the older version.

I know i can use pkg_resources and require a certain version, but if i try to install and use another version it just replaces the other one.

Comment: You can use virtual environment in Python. With virtual environment, you can install different versions of a module. You can find more information here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: are you using virtual environments?

Comment: An alternative to a virtual environment is to update your older scripts to work with a more current package.  Newer packages may contain fixes and vulnerability patches.  If that is not practical to update your older scripts, then you will need to use a virtual environment as noted by m.i.cosacak.

Comment: Thank you will look into that! @m.i.cosacak

Comment: I can't update them because newer versions caused some issues with functions, and they're not fixed yet, maybe in future releases.  @cadvena

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest solution would be to use virtual environments for one or both of your scripts. This is however not recommended in the long run if you want to scale and manage. You should switch up the script using the older version or move to something like a docker based solution.

Comment: Can you explain the docker based solution a bit more?

Comment: Docker is a containerisation tool that can deliver software packages in something called a container. These containers are isolated from each other and hence can have different packages. You can take a look at this tutorial for an idea on how to create docker images https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-a-python-script-using-docker/